# npm says says "webpack not installed Install webpack to start bundling" even though I have already installed webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, webpack, command-line-interface

I'm trying to make a webpage with CSS Modules and Webpack following the instructions on [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-2-getting-started/). I was fine until I was to run `npm start`, and then this is the error it gave me:

```sh
> css-modules@1.0.0 start /Users/username/Desktop/css-modules
> webpack && open index.html


webpack not installed

Install webpack to start bundling: 
  $ npm install --save-dev webpack

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! css-modules@1.0.0 start: `webpack && open index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the css-modules@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2020-05-06T04_09_47_528Z-debug.log
```

…even though I have installed webpack.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you see webpack folder in Users\username\node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes, I see the folder.

Comment: running webpack from cmd from the directory where the package.json is located gives anything?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think you're saying run `webpack` from /Users/username/Desktop/css-modules. I did that, installed webpack-cli, but then got `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "build" is not an absolute path!
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).
`

Comment: okay we are advancing, there's a problem in your webpack configuration file, can you upload it please?

Comment: It's the same one as on the CSS-Tricks page: `module.exports = {
  entry: './src',
  output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};`